# How to format external drive? Can create new volume but format stuck at 0%

Tags: external-hard-drive

So I'm hoping the drive isn't dead. The drive is a WD My Passport and was given to me to fix. When I plug it in I can hear the drive spinning and the light blink. At first the drive would freeze up the whole PC but I have since been able to install the latest firmware and since then my Windows 7 PC can see the drive but it cannot seem to format it.

I have tried to format it through the Disk Management page and through the command prompt. I then tried doing it through DISKPART but it does the same. Is this drive just dead?

```
C:\Windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: 

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online         1862 GB  1024 KB

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Disk attributes cleared successfully.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> create partition primary

DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition.

DISKPART> format fs=ntfs label="Passport" quick

    0 percent completed
```

Comment: Can you check and post the S.M.A.R.T. value of your harddrive?

Comment: I checked with wmic and it gave me OK OK. Should I check with a 3rd party tool to get more information? Edit: Actually, if I have two partitions on my main harddrive would it give me an OK for each drive letter? Because if yes, then it's probably not picking up the external.

Comment: You may use [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/)

Comment: The health status says N/A. Doing an error check now. Is there something in particular you'd need to see? https://imgur.com/auJvZ9k https://imgur.com/9SZfGKe

Comment: Usually it will give you a screen about the health like [this](http://www.hdtune.com/health_failed.png), but some external drive may not display correctly at sometime, can you try [CrystalDiskInfo Standard Edition](http://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html)? Besides, how old is the hard drive?

btwm, The error checking process will take a long time. You may want to scan it later.

Comment: Uh oh https://imgur.com/a3417Z4 I guess this means this drive is a goner?

Comment: Yup, it is suggested to have a replacement and don’t storage important data to it, but the drive seems young, just 87 count with 307 hours, you may proceed the error scan overnight first to check the error rate. It may still possible to storage some non-critical data like movie until it totally dead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll just go and find a new drive :)

Comment: you are welcome, I will post it as a answer. Would you mind to accept it so this question will mark as completed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the health of you drive with [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html). If it reports "WARNING" or "BAD", it is suggested to have a replacement, you may want to do a completed error scanning with [HD TUne](http://www.hdtune.com/) to verify the health status.